# LEFT JOIN tables with EJBQL

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejbql

I am trying to join two EJB's using EJBQL (with an underlying MySQL data source). The two tables in question are

```
Machine
  - Hostname
  - ... unrelated fields ...
```

and

```
Location
 - Code
 - Human readable description
```

The tables should be LEFT joined on the location code and the first three characters of the machine's hostname. In straight up MySQL the command is:

```
SELECT * FROM machine m LEFT JOIN location l ON (SUBSTRING(m.`Name`, 1,3) = l.`Code`);
```

When  I put a similar thing into EJBQL I get all sorts of errors raning from null poninter exceptions to invalid syntax exceptions -- here's what I have tried:

```
query="SELECT NEW someObj(m, loc) FROM Machine as m " +
      "LEFT JOIN FETCH Location as loc " +
      "WHERE (SUBSTRING(m.hostname, 1, :length) = loc.code)"
```

I've also tried using "ON" instead of "WHERE" -- but EJBQL comes back with an unexpected keyword when I use ON...

So -- has anyone succeeded in doing something like this before? The documentation for EJBQL seems to indicate that LEFT join is OK, so I'm not sure what the deal is...

Thanks

---

Edit: The exception I am getting is:

`outer or full join must be followed by path expression` -- it was buried  in the same line as the null pointer deal

Edit 2:

There is no relation between a Machine and a Location, unfortunately I cannot change that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no relation between the two, and if you really only need the `Machine`object, what you can do is change the `LEFT JOIN FETCH` to an `IN` statement, as in (pseudo-code):

```
select from Machine m 
where (SUBSTRING(m.hostname, 1, :length) in (some kind of logic about Location)
```